# Visual Basic read, split, modify .txt file

Tags: vb.net

I'm using visual basic 2010 and im a new user. I have my project called mini database.
I want to export and display my text file in my program.

> ```
> 05655606515|Working|John
> 12345456445|Working|Alex
> 42348564041|Not Working|Jean
> ```

I have my 3 columns table and i want an unlimited rows. The rows and depends on how many lines are there in the text file.

The first column a text box, which i can modify what i like to enter on it.
The second column is a combo box which i can select if it is working or not.
And the third column is also a textbox which i can type the name of a user.

Please help me to have my project. Thank you stackoverflow!

Comment: Please show us your previous programming attempts ie. some actual programming language listing. It'd be helpful if you could explain in your question what is the exact problem and which parts of your code already work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a form with a textbox, combo box, and a second textbox.
2. Add a command button to save the data, one to show data, and possibly one to cancel and one to exit.
3. Fill the combobox with the appropriate items.
4. In the click handler for the save button, write the data to a file with "append".
5. The show data button can read the file display the text in a multiline text box or rich text box.